# Repository tier VS Web tier VS Server side VS client side in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I'm a little bit confused about these terms in Alfresco.
What's the difference between Repository tier, Web tier (Webscripts and templates), Server Side and Client Side (Javascript), and the relation between them.
For example, can a web tier Webscript be both Server side and client side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repository Tier: This is your alfresco.war. This is the thing that makes the Alfresco repository work. It also includes an old web client called Alfresco Explorer that is mostly unused at this point.

Share Tier: This is your share.war. Alfresco Share is the web client used when people need to do basic document management or team collaboration.

Both of these are web applications so they run in "the web tier".

The Alfresco web script framework is used to provide a RESTful interface. The potentially confusing thing is that both the repository tier and the share tier contain the web script framework.

The web script framework is an implementation of the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern. Controllers are written in server-side JavaScript or Java. So that's one place you can write server-side JavaScript with Alfresco. There are other places as well.

Server-side JavaScript means the JavaScript is running entirely on the server, whether that is running in the alfresco.war or the share.war doesn't matter. The point is it is entirely server-side--there is no web browser involved.

Finally, client-side JavaScript is JavaScript that runs within the JavaScript interpreter that is built-in to the web browser running on the client's machine. Like most web applications today, Alfresco Share makes use of a LOT of client-side JavaScript.

So a typical interaction with Alfresco Share might look like this:

1. Browser requests a page. The web script framework in the Share web application runs some server-side JavaScript and ultimately returns a response in the form of an HTML page rendered in the browser.
2. On the page in the browser, there might be some client-side JavaScript that runs to handle processing within that web page.
3. The user clicks something causing the client-side JavaScript to invoke a web script running in the Share web application. This might happen asynchronously (without causing the entire page to refresh).
4. That web script could have a controller written in server-side JavaScript. If it needs any data from the Alfresco repository it will make a call to a web script running in the Alfresco web application.
5. The web script on the repository may also contain server-side JavaScript that processes the request and returns a response to the server-side JavaScript running in Alfresco Share.
6. The server-side JavaScript running in Alfresco Share processes the response it got from the Alfresco repository and returns a response to the client.

The server-side JavaScript leverages the Alfresco JavaScript API. The client-side JavaScript leverages client-side libraries like YUI and Dojo as well as some Alfresco-specific client-side libraries. So you might have a web script that produces a page that contains client-side JavaScript or you might have client-side JavaScript that invokes a server-side JavaScript, but you'd never have the same thing running on both the server-side and the client-side.